# What comes after combinations?

Tags: calculus, permutations, combinations

Permutations are n!/(n-r)! and combinations are n!/(n-r)!r! which limit the amount of possibility, But what comes after combinations. n!/(n-r)!r!r!. This new type of super combination would limit the number of combinations. Is this a real thing and what would it limit?

Comment: It is not a real thing.

Comment: Not exactly a "*super combination*" but lookup the [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Theorem).

Comment: It isn’t in general an integer. Permutations and combinations are counting things, so whatever you call your generalization, it isn’t a combinatorial thing. There is a generalization which covers both, multinominal:$$\binom{n}{k_1,\dots,k_j}$$ where $k_1+\cdots k_j=n.$ Then $$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}=\binom{n}{n-r,1,1,\cdots,1}\\\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}=\binom{n}{r,n-r}.$$

Answer (score 3):

One Reason you might suspect that this "isn't a thing" in combinatorics is the fact that this super combination isn't always an integer. For example, for $n = 3$ and $r = 2$, then
$$
\frac{3!}{1!2!2!} = \frac{6}{1\cdot 2\cdot 2} = \frac{3}{2}
$$
so that this super combination can't be counting anything.